# JIRA with script runner, send custom email

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-plugin

I'm using Script Runner plugin with JIRA to send a custom email when an issue is resolved.

The email is sent, but the problem is that the content of this email is added as a comment to the corresponding issue.

Is there any solution to avoid this ?

Note : Scripts are writed in Groovy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution by asking this question on Atlassian site :

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/328038/

Answer : When an issue is sent to "issues@mycompany.com", I configured JIRA to create a user for every CC adresses so they can receive email when the issue is resolved. But sometimes, the email adress "issues@mycompany.com" is not the direct recipient of the email, it is put in the CC field. So the user "issues@mycompany.com" is created ...